# How can I use azimuth, pitch and roll values to determine whether a device has been tilted up or down?

Tags: android, android-sensors

By using the following code:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel,mValuesMagnet);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix,
SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, R2);
SensorManager.getOrientation(R2, mValuesOrientation);
```

I get three orientation values (azimuth,pitch and roll). How can I use three orientation values to determine whether device has been tilted up or down?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with something called Gimbal Lock (basically the angle values are going crazy when you reach certain values), I suggest you start researching Rotation Matrices.

You should also specify what kind of device movement you call "a tilt", and in which orientation your app works.